# How to identify unique data between two dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I am sorry if the title isn't the best. I am not sure how to put this in the correct terms.

I am doing some filtering using dpylr. So to give a little background, `df1` is a list of all of the human genes. `df2` has a list of gene involved in some pathway. The software that gives me the list for `df2` doesn't always use the correct gene name that is in df1 so they get skipped when I use this filter

```
filtered <- df1 %>%
    filter(gene.name %in% df2$V1)
```

So I am missing some of the data that I am interested in. I was wondering if there was a way to compare the new df called `filtered` to `df2` with some code that marks unique difference? The majority of the `filtered` data frame will be the same as `df2` but `df2` will just have the gene names that were incorrect. The reason I want to do this is because I want to go back and correct the gene names. I df1 and df2 are much larger than the examples so it isn't easy to catch.

Here is an example of what I am saying so maybe it will make more sense

df1

`gene.name
 ADCY1
 ADCY2
 ADCY3
 ADCY4`

df2

`gene.name
 AC1
 ADCY2
 AC3
 ADCY4`

filtered

`gene.name
 ADCY2
 ADCY4`

Comment: Did you search first?  This has been asked many times.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to get. Are you trying to find genes in `df2` that are not in `df1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: The `df1`, `df2`, `filtered` examples at the bottom are a good start. Please add in that same format your desired result.

Comment: @divibisan I am filtering `df1` by `df2` giving `filtered`. I want to know what is different between `filtered` and `df` so for example `df2` is four genes and `filtered` has two genes. I want to know what two genes `df2` has that `filtered` doesn't so I can go back to df2 and find the correct gene name for AC1 and AC3

Comment: @NelsonGon I don't need to merge the data frames

Comment: Seems like creating `filtered` isn't really necessary. Add a column to `df1` instead: `df1 %>% mutate(in_df2 = gene.name %in% df2$V1)`.

Comment: If you want genes in `df2` that are not in `df1`, is this what you are looking for: `df2$gene.name[!df2$gene.name %in% df1$gene.name]`?

Comment: @Gregor Oh... wow that actually is perfect

Comment: Okay, voting to close as typo. You basically wanted to create a column and used a command to subset instead. (Do please be more specific about your desired output in the future. Showing an example *and* describing in words is best.)

Comment: @Gregor That is fine with me. I am sorry about that. I search for what I was trying to describe but I couldn't seem to find what I was looking for. I will do that in the future. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another fun way to get the not-in functionality is to write little function like

```
'%notin%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))
```

Then you can get the answer in a nice tidy way:

```
unique_differences<-df2 
    %>% filter(gene.name %notin% unlist(df1))
```

Comment: That works very nice as well. I changed the name of df2 to `filter` and that gave me some issues because the software thought I was listing `filter` twice. So if anyone is reading this, don't do that. Thanks for the answer!! I appreciate you taking the time to write that out.